# Convert string to timestamp python

Tags: python, list, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to convert the list of str to the list of timestamps, then want to create the list of time delta of timestamps using total_seconds()

```
from datetime import datetime 
a = ['091122333','092222222','093333333']
for i in a:
    datetime.strptime(str(i),'%H:%M:%S.%f')
print(a)
```

It shows the error code of time data '091122333' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'

I want to make timestamp 09(%H)11(%M)22(%S)333(%F) if possible.
Could you give me the advice above?

Thank you very much...

Comment: Could you explain what you did in that code piece of yours? What is the purpose of str(i), and what happens to the returned value of datetime.strptime?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken... I meant for i in a: then str(i).

Comment: it shows  error code : time data '091122333' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'

Comment: please have a look at the docs first. especially [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first change the representation ( You have **`:`** which is not present in list of string in `a`) and how You manage what is returned from datetime.strptime (You have to store the value while You iterate through list) like that:

```
from datetime import datetime 
a = ['091122333','092222222','093333333']
for t in range(len(a)):
    a[t] = datetime.strptime(a[t],'%H%M%S%f')
delta = a[1]-a[0] 
print(delta.total_seconds())
```

Answer (score 0):

The format passed to `strptime` should represent the format used in the string (there are no colons in your string):

```
from datetime import datetime
a = ['091122333', '092222222', '093333333']

for i in a:
    dt = datetime.strptime(str(i), '%H%M%S%f')
    print(dt)
```

Out:

```
1900-01-01 09:11:22.333000
1900-01-01 09:22:22.222000
1900-01-01 09:33:33.333000
```